# Owner draw the text of a button with the Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to owner/custom draw the text of a button, but only the text (or the content). So I can  render the button with multiple colored fonts.

If I handle `WM_DRAWITEM` I have to paint the entire button. I want to only paint the text.

Is there some API I can call to have windows paint the button without the text, and then I can paint the text myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw the entire button yourself.  However, you can use the `DrawFrameControl()` function, or the `DrawThemeParentBackground/Ex()` and `DrawThemeBackground/Ex()` functions if CommCtrl v6 is enabled on XP+, to let Windows draw the button's background and borders for you.  You can then draw your desired text on top of that.